# dissmissing the Progress Bar after sometime

Tags: android, timer, progress-bar

I have created a progress Bar which I need to show on clicking the Button that plays the particular sound. Now I want the timer to be displayed below the ProgressBar and want both the ProgressBar and Timer to run Simultaneously along with the length of the sound.

Also when the sound gets finished, I want the PregressBar and Timer to be invisible again so that I can start it again for the another Sound.

Can anybody please help me in this?

Thanks,
david

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `AsyncTask` class here 
start the timer and ProgressBar on `onPreExecute`
Play the particular sound inside `doInBackground` and return when it is finished
So in `onPostExecute` you can make that PregressBar and Timer stop and invisible
And Button on click listener you can start its execution AsyncTask.`execute`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Can you please tell me how exactly can I make the ProgressBar invisible? I know that for the ProgressDialog there is the "dismiss()" method but how do I do that for the ProgressBar?